# Enforce a time limit on the number of uploads per user

Tags: php, cookies, file-upload, session-management

I've done a lot of searching on SE and particularly here in regards to preventing issues or attacks for an image based website to accept image uploads, but I haven't seen anyone mention the idea of adding a limit on the number of file uploads per a period of time on the server, and wondered if this would be a good addition?

So far I have read:

- [Risks of a php image upload form](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form)
- [Secure PHP upload form & storage](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29719/secure-php-upload-form-storage?rq=1)
- [Secure PHP File Upload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950331/secure-php-file-upload-script/7065880#7065880)
- [Secure File Upload in PHP Web Applications](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/file_upload.php)
- [Why File Upload Forms are a Major Security Threat](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/)

Are there any other security precautions to think about? I did read how images should be renamed. I've been thinking about using a 3rd party image API for the site, but I'm still looking into its security and implementation.

Comment: It's not clear what risks you are concerned about.  Why is it a problem if a client completes a web form multiple times?

Comment: To prevent spam I would imagine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge you are going to face is how you identify the remote user.  It's not very hard for a remote client to change their "appearance" (browser, browser version, cookies, browser plugins, IP address, etc) and look like a new client.

If you place a cookie on their browser that indicates they've uploaded a file they can clear that cookie and upload again.

If you add a flag to their session (tracked server side matching a session cookie you give them) indicating they've done an upload, then they can create multiple accounts.

The better approach may be to:

1. Decrease the value of spamming your site, taking away their
   incentive
2. Improve your ability to detect and remove spam messages
   (either before or after they are posted)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are trying to limit a user from abusing the file upload functionality by uploading files via automated scripts or something similar. There are two ways to handle this:

1. Create a control on the server side preventing the user from uploading greater than X number of files in Y time. For example, only 10 images per every 5 minutes.
2. Implement a CAPTCHA of some sort. Here's an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/9986/11489) that talks about what you can do.

You can also limit the size of each image upload, and have some sort of a routine that enforces a limit on how much a user can totally upload every day. For example, a daily limit for a user can be 500M, depending on how the site is used.